# Style BasedOn suddenly not working

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, wpf-controls

These simple styles just stopped working out of the blue. They worked fine until today.

```
<Style x:Key="textColumnElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,1" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="textColumnEditingElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0" />
</Style>
```

These both shows errors on the `BasedOn` property.

```
The resource "{x:Type TextBlock}" could not be resolved.
The resource "{x:Type TextBox}" could not be resolved.
```

If I copy and pase one of the styles right next to itself, there is no error on the pasted style.

```
<Style x:Key="noErrorOnThisStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,1" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="textColumnElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,1" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="textColumnEditingElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It turns out the only difference is the existence of a key `noErrorOnThisStyle`?

Comment: Yes. Simply declaring the Style a few lines above or below makes the error disappear. Also note that for two similar Styles based on a TextBox, one says TextBox could not be resolved and the other doesn't.

Comment: i have the same problem when the type is stackpanel . I am also using vs 2012 update3

Answer (score 1):

In fact in your case the BasedOn attribute is not needed. Just write

```
<Style x:Key="textColumnElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,1" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="textColumnEditingElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0" />
</Style>
```

When BasedOn is not set, BasedOn point to the default style of the type specified by the TargetType attribute.

Regards

Claude

Comment: That doesn't answer why it stopped working just now. The code worked fine for YEARS. I installed VS2012 Update 3 recently.

Comment: The default style is not the same as the current style however and afaik `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"` uses the current style.

Comment: If I change the default style for TextBlock, then I have to use BasedOn to descend from it. However, if you do not change the default style, BasedOn is not needed.